# Why is php 7 2 to 3 times faster than previous versions?

Tags: php, php-7

Which changes have been done in php 7 to make it 2 to 3 times faster than previous versions?
I have searched for it,  but only found changes in the Zend Engine. Has there been any other change done for the sake of performance?

Comment: The real implementation of OOP it's a reason